# Shimano 8515 question

Tags: shimano, specialized-bikes

[image]

I was wondering if this was a good derailleur, found a specialized bike on Craigslist with this on it.

Answer (score 1):

That says 8SIS (i.e. 8 speed Shimano Index System), a thing Shimano used to mark some of their derailleurs with when the system was still new-ish.

It's a basic Alivio level part -- nothing special, on the mid to low range. You can replace it with any 7-9 speed Shimano derailleur.

Comment: Would it be worth getting if it is only like 60 dollars?

Comment: We don't do product valuations, but a compatible new replacement derailleur (of higher quality) is about 20 dollars.